# Appending new line with variable in bash script

Tags: shell, sh

I'm trying to execute a shell script with a cli command which have a variable like below.

eg:

```
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
vnl-cli -s http://localhost:8080 -u adminusername -p adminpass --vinscan --target_url=http://demo.testfire.net --start_date=$DATE | tail -n1
```

so when I echo this script like,

```
echo "vnl-cli -s http://localhost:8080 -u adminusername -p adminpass --vinscan --target_url=http://demo.testfire.net --start_date=$DATE | tail -n1"
```

the above script showing with new line after variable.

```
vnl-cli -s http://localhost:8080 -u adminusername -p adminpass --vinscan --target_url=http://demo.testfire.net --start_date=2021-01-19
 | tail -n1
```

This should be in a single line like

```
vnl-cli -s http://localhost:8080 -u adminusername -p adminpass --vinscan --target_url=http://demo.testfire.net --start_date=2021-01-19 | tail -n1
```

Comment: That shouldn't be. Command substitution with backquotes or `$(...)` trims trailing newline(s) so `echo "... $DATE ..."` should NOT cause a newline except at the end of the whole line. What shell type and version, and environment (at least OS) are you using? What does `echo "$DATE" | od -tx1` or even better `printf %s "$DATE" | od -tx1` or `printf %q "$DATE"` show?

Comment: Hi, I'm using MacOs Big Sur (11.1).

Comment: I have tried with ```--start_date=$($DATE | tr '\r\n' ' ')| tail -n1``` . That also not worked for me.

Comment: It is not showing new line in my code.
Could you please upload your full code.

Comment: could you please tell your shell version
Just run `$SHELL --version`

Comment: GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin20)

Comment: Please find the below code
```
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
export ID=`vnl-cli -s http://localhost:8080 -u adminusername -p adminpass --vinscan --target_url=http://demo.testfire.net --start_date=$($DATE | tr '\r\n' ' ') | tail -n1`
echo "ID......" $ID
```

Comment: `$DATE | ...` makes no sense, as the value of `DATE` is an actual date, not a command to run. Further, `date` will not output a carriage return on macOS, nor will a command substitution capture a trailing newline, making the use of `tr` unnecessary.

Comment: @alecxs I'm talking about the pipe to `tr`.

Comment: @ajinzrathod `$SHELL --version` tells you absolutely nothing about the current shell.  It gives you information only about the shell that the user prefers to run.  `SHELL` is in no way related to the shell that is currently running, in the same way that EDITOR or PAGER is not related the currently running shell.